# Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit when sending base64 post request Axios

Tags: node.js, axios

When sending a post request with a Base64 encoded pdf as the body i recieve the error

Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit

I have tried setting both of the following

'maxContentLength': Infinity,
'maxBodyLength': Infinity

in the request config

```
const result = await axios({
            url: `the url`,
            headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'ParentId': record_id,
                'Name': file_name,
                'body': body,
                'Description': description ? description : "",
                'maxContentLength': Infinity,
                'maxBodyLength': Infinity
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are setting

```
'maxContentLength': Infinity,
'maxBodyLength': Infinity
```

In your data object. It should be inside the config object, **outside** the data object.

Comment: Indeed!! Thank you for pointing that out! Working as expected now.

Answer (score 47):

That is what worked for me:

```js
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: posturl,
    data: formData,
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=' + formData.getBoundary()}
})
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the maxContentLength and maxBodyLength only one time for all axios calls you can register an interceptor.
Add this code before all your axios calls and you body size problems are gone.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    request.maxContentLength = Infinity;
    request.maxBodyLength = Infinity;
    return request;
})
```