# React onSubmit e.preventDefault() not working sometimes + Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, page-refresh, onsubmit

Right now I'm facing this strange problem in React where the onSubmit function with e.preventDefault() does avoid refreshing the page sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't.

I've created two hooks to keep track of the uploaded files and their progress bars.

```
const [ uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles ] = useState([]);
const [ uploadPercentages, setUploadPercentages ] = useState([]);
```

The onSubmit function uses Axios to make a request to the backend.

```
const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!!file) {
            // Show file box on screen
            let index = addUpload(file);

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", file);

            try {
                await axios.post("/upload_video", formData, {
                    onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                        const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
                        let progress = uploadPercentages.concat(0)
                        progress[index] = Math.round((loaded * 100) / total)

                        setUploadPercentages(progress);
                    }
                })
            } catch(err) {
                // Handlers
            }
        }
        return false // trying something different to avoid refresh
}
```

Just in case, the addUpload function has shown little to no relation with the source of the problem. I took it away to test it and things behave the same way.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Edit:

Here is the form.

```
<form className="choose-file" onSubmit={onSubmit}> 
            
     <div className="file-container">
         { file ?
             <p> { file.name } </p>
             :
             <label className="file-label" htmlFor="customFile">
                 <input type="file" className="file-input" id="customFile" onChange={ onChange }/>
                 <p><i className="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i></p>
                 <p>Click here to select file</p>
             </label>   
          }
     </div>

     <div className="file-options">
          <input type="submit" value="Upload" className="file-input" id="customFile"/>
          <button type="button" onClick={ removeFile }>Delete</button>
     </div>

</form>
```

"file" is a third hook just to show the user the name of the file they just selected.

Edit 2:

The problems seems to appear only when file sizes are greater than 100MB. Besides, once the problem shows up, it starts to happen to every single file no matter its size.

For instance if I upload a 7MB file, page does not refresh, if I then try a 100MB file it starts refreshing for every upcoming file and all console logs after the axios post are never seen again.

Edit 3:

Since I'm running a local backend on Flask, I tried disconnecting it from the React app to see what happens. For small files the request to the backend is only asked once and the alarm inside the catch(err) triggers. For big files the request is asked around four times and it never reaches the catch part.

Send help

Comment: show us your form too.

Comment: @cybercoder sure!

Comment: You can try removing the `async` in the `onSubmit` function and change the axios code accordingly

Comment: @deepakgupta191199 yes, I tried this out and it didn't work. Console logs after the axios method don't show up neither

Comment: what happens if you call that like this: ```form onsubmit={e=>{e.preventDefault(); onSubmit()}}``` and remove event from your function?

Comment: @cybercoder it still refresh. I also put some console logs after the axios and they don't show up when the file is to big (100MB+). I will add some new info I've collected to the main question.

Comment: Are you sure there's noting in parent component(s) which affects? this is weird!

Comment: @cybercoder yes, right now this is the only component in the project. There was a second component rendering file info but I took it away and nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe you need to set maxContentLength and maxBodyLength to Infinity. See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63611054/12200445

Comment: @deepakgupta191199 no, this doesn't work. Something weird is that axios is not displaying errors when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the problem turned out to be something as simple as saving the files in the React's public folder.

My guess is that this caused the whole project to refresh every time a change is detected inside this folder. For small objects the time it takes almost zero, but for big files it takes a while, causing the components to refresh as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem in not with `addUpload` but with the `async`. You can try this way

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 
 // After collecting formData ... 
 // in the *try* block do this
 
 const post = axios.post("/upload_video", formData, {
                    onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                        const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
                        let progress = uploadPercentages.concat(0)
                        progress[index] = Math.round((loaded * 100) / total)

                        setUploadPercentages(progress);
                    }
  
  post.then(() => {alert('Done posting')}) // inside this you can do whatever you want to do after axios.post 
}
```

**EDIT : **

Since you mentioned in the comment that the solution does not work, here's an alternative.

*Declare a new function*

```
const async post = () => {
 // Get the formData here

 await axios.post("/upload_video", formData, {
                    onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                        const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
                        let progress = uploadPercentages.concat(0)
                        progress[index] = Math.round((loaded * 100) / total)

                        setUploadPercentages(progress);
                    }
}

// Now in the onSubmit function

const onSubmit =  (e) => {
 
 e.preventDefalut();
 post()
}
```

This is the final solution I have. Hope this works...

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work, although something important to mention is that the alert inside the .then() never showed up.

Comment: Please try the new **Edited** version

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I tried the alert in the .then() once again to see if it pop up but it didn't either.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing problems with using arrow functions as **HANDLERS**,
try turning it into normal function

```
async function HandelOnSubmit (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!!file) {
            // Show file box on screen
            let index = addUpload(file);

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", file);

            try {
                await axios.post("/upload_video", formData, {
                    onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                        const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
                        let progress = uploadPercentages.concat(0)
                        progress[index] = Math.round((loaded * 100) / total)

                        setUploadPercentages(progress);
                    }
                })
            } catch(err) {
                // Handlers
            }
        }
        return false // trying something different to avoid refresh }
```