# preventDefault() method not preventing page reload ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, multer, formidable

I am trying to upload files using `multer` or `formidable`. The files are uploaded properly and also stored in the `public` folder. I used create-react-app to start with React project.

The problem arises when I click on the submit button to upload the data. I used the fetch API for making the POST request. The page reloads after I click on the submit button, and anything I log on the console is refreshed as well. This was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64200669/15045143), but I want to know how do I prevent my page from reloading? Should I store my images outside the `public` folder?

Here is my `handleSubmit()` function that calls when form is submitted:-

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("poster", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
    let res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/post/exhibition", {
       method: "POST",
       body: formData
    })
    const json = await res.json()
    console.log(json)
 }
```

EDIT:- Handling `onSubmit`

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
....
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the part where `handleSubmit` is used?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski check the edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because when your upload is successful, webpack detects a new file and reloads the page.

from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2541#issuecomment-308750412

> I don't think we'll do this as it seems like people generally don't use public folder for uploads. And it wouldn't work in production anyway.
> I would recommend to use a separate server (which you need anyway) and separate folder for image uploads, and have the app load images from a different host/port (just like it would in production, e.g. from a CDN).

Comment: What does "And it wouldn't work in production anyway." mean?

Comment: It means when you build your app and deploy it on a production server (e.g. your hosting server), this method won't work. @ChaitanyaSondur

Answer (score 0):

if you are using that function in `onsubmit` attribute of the form you need to return `false` from that function

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("poster", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
    let res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/post/exhibition", {
       method: "POST",
       body: formData
    })
    const json = await res.json()
    console.log(json)
    return false
 }
```

Comment: It still reloads the page.

Comment: I think the answer above is more likely your issue. As the comment in the link suggests you should not be uploading files directly to public folder. Use a separate folder for uploads instead.